# How can I fix execution reverted: ERC721: approval to current owner?

Tags: blockchain, ether, nft, erc-721, onerc721received

My contract is returning me this error:

`execution reverted: ERC721: approval to current owner`

How can I fix this?

```js
//SPDX-License-Identifier: Unlicense
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "hardhat/console.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";

contract NFTMarketplace is ERC721URIStorage {
    using Counters for Counters.Counter;
    //_tokenIds variable has the most recent minted tokenId
    Counters.Counter private _tokenIds;
    //Keeps track of the number of items sold on the marketplace
    Counters.Counter private _itemsSold;
    //owner is the contract address that created the smart contract
    address payable owner;
    //The fee charged by the marketplace to be allowed to list an NFT
    uint256 listPrice = 0.001 ether;

    //The structure to store info about a listed token
    struct ListedToken {
        uint256 tokenId;
        address payable owner;
        address payable seller;
        uint256 price;
        bool currentlyListed;
    }

    //the event emitted when a token is successfully listed
    event TokenListedSuccess(
        uint256 indexed tokenId,
        address owner,
        address seller,
        uint256 price,
        bool currentlyListed
    );

    //This mapping maps tokenId to token info and is helpful when retrieving details about a tokenId
    mapping(uint256 => ListedToken) private idToListedToken;

    constructor() ERC721("NFTMarketplace", "NFTM") {
        owner = payable(msg.sender);
    }

    function updateListPrice(uint256 _listPrice) public payable {
        require(owner == msg.sender, "Only owner can update listing price");
        listPrice = _listPrice;
    }

    function getListPrice() public view returns (uint256) {
        return listPrice;
    }

    function getLatestIdToListedToken()
        public
        view
        returns (ListedToken memory)
    {
        uint256 currentTokenId = _tokenIds.current();
        return idToListedToken[currentTokenId];
    }

    function getListedTokenForId(
        uint256 tokenId
    ) public view returns (ListedToken memory) {
        return idToListedToken[tokenId];
    }

    function getCurrentToken() public view returns (uint256) {
        return _tokenIds.current();
    }

    //The first time a token is created, it is listed here
    function createToken(
        string memory tokenURI,
        uint256 price
    ) public payable returns (uint) {
        //Increment the tokenId counter, which is keeping track of the number of minted NFTs
        _tokenIds.increment();
        uint256 newTokenId = _tokenIds.current();

        //Mint the NFT with tokenId newTokenId to the address who called createToken
        _safeMint(msg.sender, newTokenId);

        //Map the tokenId to the tokenURI (which is an IPFS URL with the NFT metadata)
        _setTokenURI(newTokenId, tokenURI);
        // setApprovalForAll(msg.sender, true);
        //Helper function to update Global variables and emit an event
        createListedToken(newTokenId, price);

        return newTokenId;
    }

    function createListedToken(uint256 tokenId, uint256 price) private {
        //Make sure the sender sent enough ETH to pay for listing
        require(msg.value == listPrice, "Hopefully sending the correct price");
        //Just sanity check
        require(price > 0, "Make sure the price isn't negative");

        //Update the mapping of tokenId's to Token details, useful for retrieval functions
        idToListedToken[tokenId] = ListedToken(
            tokenId,
            payable(address(this)),
            payable(msg.sender),
            price,
            true
        );

        _transfer(msg.sender, address(this), tokenId);
        //Emit the event for successful transfer. The frontend parses this message and updates the end user
        emit TokenListedSuccess(
            tokenId,
            address(this),
            msg.sender,
            price,
            true
        );
    }

    //This will return all the NFTs currently listed to be sold on the marketplace
    function getAllNFTs() public view returns (ListedToken[] memory) {
        uint nftCount = _tokenIds.current();
        ListedToken[] memory tokens = new ListedToken[](nftCount);
        uint currentIndex = 0;
        uint currentId;
        //at the moment currentlyListed is true for all, if it becomes false in the future we will
        //filter out currentlyListed == false over here
        for (uint i = 0; i < nftCount; i++) {
            currentId = i + 1;
            ListedToken storage currentItem = idToListedToken[currentId];
            tokens[currentIndex] = currentItem;
            currentIndex += 1;
        }
        //the array 'tokens' has the list of all NFTs in the marketplace
        return tokens;
    }

    //Returns all the NFTs that the current user is owner or seller in
    function getMyNFTs() public view returns (ListedToken[] memory) {
        uint totalItemCount = _tokenIds.current();
        uint itemCount = 0;
        uint currentIndex = 0;
        uint currentId;
        //Important to get a count of all the NFTs that belong to the user before we can make an array for them
        for (uint i = 0; i < totalItemCount; i++) {
            if (
                idToListedToken[i + 1].owner == msg.sender ||
                idToListedToken[i + 1].seller == msg.sender
            ) {
                itemCount += 1;
            }
        }

        //Once you have the count of relevant NFTs, create an array then store all the NFTs in it
        ListedToken[] memory items = new ListedToken[](itemCount);
        for (uint i = 0; i < totalItemCount; i++) {
            if (
                idToListedToken[i + 1].owner == msg.sender ||
                idToListedToken[i + 1].seller == msg.sender
            ) {
                currentId = i + 1;
                ListedToken storage currentItem = idToListedToken[currentId];
                items[currentIndex] = currentItem;
                currentIndex += 1;
            }
        }
        return items;
    }

    function executeSale(uint256 tokenId) public payable {
        uint price = idToListedToken[tokenId].price;
        address seller = idToListedToken[tokenId].seller;
        require(
            msg.value == price,
            "Please submit the asking price in order to complete the purchase"
        );

        //update the details of the token
        idToListedToken[tokenId].currentlyListed = true;
        idToListedToken[tokenId].seller = payable(msg.sender);
        _itemsSold.increment();

        //Actually transfer the token to the new owner
        _transfer(address(this), msg.sender, tokenId);
        //approve the marketplace to sell NFTs on your behalf
       
        approve(msg.sender, tokenId);

        //Transfer the listing fee to the marketplace creator
        payable(owner).transfer(listPrice);
        //Transfer the proceeds from the sale to the seller of the NFT
        payable(seller).transfer(msg.value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you be more concise on what command you are running to get this error?

Comment: Please ask questions in a way people can replicate what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting matches [an error found](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/issues/4136) in an earlier version of Open Zeppelin's ERC-721 contract.

The reason you are getting this error is because you are trying to approve the owner of the token to spend the token.

For example:

Alice owns an NFT with `tokenId` of 7.

Alice tries to call `approve()` using her own address and her own NFT's tokenId.

`approve(address(Alice), 7)` would return `"ERC721: approval to current owner"`.

Here is the `require` code that I think is being triggered:

```js
require(to != owner, "ERC721: approval to current owner");
```

The issue is inside your `executeSales()` function and comes from these lines:

```js
 _transfer(address(this), msg.sender, tokenId);
        //approve the marketplace to sell NFTs on your behalf
       
        approve(msg.sender, tokenId);
```

You are first transferring the NFT with `tokenId` to `msg.sender`, then immediately afterwards you are trying to approve `msg.sender` to spend the NFT you just sent them.

I think what you are trying to do is have `msg.sender` approve your marketplace for the token you've just sent them, if that's the case, you'd want to use the internal `_approve()` function to bypass `msg.sender` checks, and then instead of approving `msg.sender`, approve `address(this)` instead.

This will ensure that

1. `msg.sender` is sent the NFT
2. Your marketplace contract is approved to spend the NFT you sent to `msg.sender`.